# installing pycurl on osx 10.10 - don't know what to do with pycurl-7.10.5

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I'm trying to install pycurl.
I downloaded and decompressed pycurl-7.10.5.tar.gz but I don't know what to do with the output.
Could someone help me with the install. I have python 3.5 and 3.3 installed as well as the Eclipse IDE with the PyDev extension.
I'd rather stay away from unix-like command line commands if possible and install from the native OSX interface. Something always goes wrong whenever I try things in the terminal.
For example, the first line of the INSTALL file tells me to 
tar -zxvf pycurl-$VER.tar.gz
the response I get is:
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'pycurl-.tar.gz'
Thank you,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

The only real answer is to use a command line, *one that you can run the python that you need to install curl to*, i.e.:

```
pip install ./pycurl-7.10.5.tar.gz
```

if this fails try:

```
sudo pip install ./pycurl-7.10.5.tar.gz
```

in the directory that you downloaded the tar.gz to.  BTW the terminal is the native interface.  You will need to do this twice - once for each python.

You could always write a small python script to take the name of a package and do:

```
subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', name_of_package])
```

again you may need to run this with elevated privileges.  *(I don't have a Mac to try it out on)*.  The good news is that if you are connected to the net at the time then just `pip install pycurl` should download the latest compatible version and install it all in one operation.

### Missing pip?

If pip is missing then you can follow the [installing pip instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/#install-or-upgrade-pip) which consist of:
To install pip, securely download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

Then run the following (which may require administrator access):

```
python get-pip.py
```

If setuptools is not already installed, get-pip.py will install setuptools for you.

To upgrade an existing setuptools, run `pip install -U setuptools`.

Install behind a proxy:

```
python get-pip.py --proxy="[user:password@]proxy.server:port"
```

Upgrade pip

On Linux or OS X:

```
pip install -U pip
```

On Windows [5]:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Comment: Yes, I can run python.  That, I had installed a while back. However, I don't have pip, and I don't have apt-get. (I found out when I tried to use apt-get to get pip.) Either, the OSX doesn't come with it, or I deleted it accidentally a while back. In either case I'm having trouble finding it for OSX. All the info out there points me to some other install tools. Thanks

Comment: @JoeM - Added how to add a pip if it is missing.

Comment: Thank you Steve, Using your advice I was able to download Pip. I now have it successfully installed. Only question I have is that I have 3 version of python: 2.7, 3.3, and 3.5. How do I know which version I ran the "python get-pip.py" command against? I believe it was 2.7 because that is the version I get when I run python from the command line. I actually only want the latest version, 3.5, that's what I see in the Eclipse IDE. How can I "point" to 3.5? Better yet, can I get rid of 2.7 and 3.3 to avoid confusion?

Comment: For the version, in the same context run `python --version` the rest is a) a separate question, b) OS-X specific & c) Can cause problems if the OS relies on a version that you get rid of, so can't be much help here - sorry!

Comment: Hi, the reason I asked about versions is the long way around to inquire why my make command failed. I get ... 'Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-jK46FQ-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8rDnAD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-jK46FQ-build
' .... There was a lot more on the console, but this is the last error line.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, you need to set the arch flag in the env. Try this, it should build:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip3.5 install ./pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz
```